# what does "policy stance" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Meanwhile, it is unlikely that the G-7 will implement a much different **policy stance** once officials return to their national capitals.

source: http://www.bloomberg.com/view/articles/2016-05-27/central-banks-can-t-go-it-alone-anymore

What does "policy stance" mean in this sentence?

Comment: The usual collocation is "to adopt a stance" rather than "implement" one.

Answer (score 0):

Policy stance in this instance is referring to the opinion they have on a particular policy. At the G-7 meeting, officials may be totally supportive a policy put forward however, when they return to their national capitals, they will take a different stance on the policy, not implementing it or ignoring the measures put in place to ensure that it is carried out.